# transfer html var to php

Tags: php, html, canvas

I am new to php, if I write a piece of html5 canvas code, and want to store the var effort value in the canvas to the php session for transfer to mysql, how to do this? Corresponding code are in star, thx in advance

```
<div id="aside">
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="600" height="500" style="border:1px solid #c3c3c3;">
</canvas>
<script>
var bodyStyle = document.body.style; 
bodyStyle.mozUserSelect = 'none'; 
bodyStyle.webkitUserSelect = 'none'; 


var img = new Image(); 
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'); 
canvas.style.backgroundColor='transparent'; 
canvas.style.position = 'absolute'; 
var imgs = ['p_2.jpg','p_3.jpg','p_4.jpg','p_5.jpg','p_6.jpg','p_7.jpg','p_8.jpg','p_9.jpg','p_10.jpg','p_12.jpg'
       ,'p_12.jpg','p_13.jpg','p_14.jpg','p_15.jpg','p_16.jpg','p_17.jpg','p_18.jpg','p_19.jpg','p_20.jpg','p_21.jpg','p_22.jpg',
       'p_23.jpg','p_24.jpg','p_25.jpg','p_26.jpg']; 
var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*24); 
img.src = imgs[num]; 

img.addEventListener('load', function(e) { 
var ctx; 
// var w = img.width, 
//     h = img.height; 
var w=600;
    h=500;
var offsetX = canvas.offsetLeft, 
    offsetY = canvas.offsetTop; 
var mousedown = false; 

function layer(ctx) { 
    ctx.fillStyle = 'gray'; 
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h); 
} 

function eventDown(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    mousedown=true; 
} 

function eventUp(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    mousedown=false; 
} 

function eventMove(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    if(mousedown) { 
         if(e.changedTouches){ 
             e=e.changedTouches[e.changedTouches.length-1]; 
         } 
         var x = (e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft || e.pageX) - offsetX || 0, 
             y = (e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop || e.pageY) - offsetY || 0; 
         with(ctx) { 
             beginPath() 
             //arc(x, y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
             rect(x,y,20,20);
             fill(); 
         } 
    } 
} 
function consulation(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   var num = 0;
  var datas = canvas.getImageData(0,0,w,h);
  for (var i = 0; i < datas.data.length; i++) {
    if (datas.data[i] == 0) {
        num++;
     };
  };
  **var effort=num/(w*h); **

}
canvas.width=w; 
canvas.height=h; 
canvas.style.backgroundImage='url('+img.src+')'; 
ctx=canvas.getContext('2d'); 
ctx.fillStyle='transparent'; 
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);//绘制矩形 
layer(ctx); 

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'; 

canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', eventDown); 
canvas.addEventListener('touchend', eventUp); 
canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', eventMove); 
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', eventDown); 
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', eventUp); 
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', eventMove);
canvas.addEventListener("click",consulation);

 }); 

</script>


</html>

</div>

</body>
</html>
<?php

**$_SESSION["EFFORT"]=$effort;**
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely not the best solution, however, you can use an ajax request to call a PHP script and pass the var from Javascript to the PHP script.

Comment: hi, as i know, ajax post( ) loads some data from the server(php) to the client(js). How could i send data from client(js) to server(php)

Comment: You can capture client data, `getElementById()` or add an event listener to check for data and pass it along the URL `phpfile.php?passVar=myVarValue`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with cookies, both javascript and PHP can set and read those.

As the other poster mentioned, AJAX is also an option.

I beleive you can also set a URL fragment (domain.com/blah#stuff) that can be parsed by PHP,  but at that point you'd be reloading the page anyway so you might as well do it with a POST value.